# Force docker compose download specific version of php (8.1.0 but not 8.1.9)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I've a docker compose have the following syntax

```
  php810:
    container_name: web_php_810
    image: php:8.1.0-fpm-alpine
    build: ./php810
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php810/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php810/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

after docker-compose up, i enter into the conatain type php -v, it shows php8.1.9, anyone know how to force the version to be 8.1.0?

Comment: You shouldn't have both `image` and `build`. What's in `php810/Dockerfile`?

Comment: @phil you can have build and image (otherwise how would docker compose know what's the name of the final image?). It's only a matter of precedance.

Comment: @phil the documentation doesn't say redundant, that is your interpretation of it. however if you build the image to later push it to a registry (say GHCR or Amazon, doesn't really matter) they you need to prefix the image name with the registry name. Where would you specify that if you don't specify an image name?

Comment: @phil i just found my dockerfile is still using FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine, forgot to change FROM php:8.1.0-fpm-alpine, so the problem is fixed after re-build

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your local Dockerfile, which you didn't post so I can't validate it. Probably you upgrade the packages (including php) inside.

But here is the problem:

When you specify the `build` option, then docker-compose will look for a Dockerfile, build a new docker image and give it the name specified in the `image` option. So in this scenario, what you specify in `image` is not downloaded from any registry, but is built locally. This is why the image name can be anything you want.

If you only specify `image` and no `build` option, then docker-compose will try to download the image specified from a known registry. It will fail if it cannot find that image.

For your case it is better to change the image name to anything you want and you will see that docker-compose doesn't complain.

Also you can see that the original image works correctly by running this:

```bash
# delete the image you previously built
docker rmi php:8.1.0-fpm-alpine

# download original and check the version
docker run -ti --rm php:8.1.0-fpm-alpine php -v
```

Comment: TIL that the `image` config can be used to tag the built image. Seems poorly documented

Comment: Seems highly unlikely that OP is actually building images for the [php docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and they probably aren't publishing either